# AnkhSVN - Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I'm trying to Branch Solution with VS 2010 SP1 and AnkhSVN 2.3.11269 (latest version).

That's resulting in:

> SharpSvn.SvnUnsupportedFeatureException: Source and destination URLs appear not to point to the same repository.

My Source URL:

> svn+ssh://svn@MyCompany.SomeSvnProvider.com/MyCompany/MyProject/

AnkhSVN suggests the following Branch URL:

> svn+ssh://svn@MyCompany.SomeSvnProvider.com/branches/

It stands out that the Source URL contains MyCompany and MyProject, while the suggested Branch URL contains neither.

How can I successfully branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the URL suggested by AnkhSVN was wrong.  The correct URL would be

> svn+ssh://svn@MyCompany.SomeSvnProvider.com/MyCompany/MyProject/branches/